# Magento2: how override translates in language pack?

Tags: magento2, language-package

I installed language pack in **`app/i18n/magento2translations/language_nl_nl/`** with file **nl_NL.csv** It's works perfect.
Also, I added in custom theme file **`app/design/frontend/COMPANY/PROJECT/i18n/nl_NL.csv`** with my custom translates, but it not working (mode: developer, static content and caches were cleaned).
When I move custom translates to language pack's **nl_NL.csv** custom translates works fine.
I think the language pack has more priority as a custom theme **i18n translates**.

How override translates in language pack in the correct way?

Comment: Please try to switch mode to default or production and check again.

Comment: try `rm -rf pub/static/*`, `rm -rf var/cache/*` from m2 root folder.

Comment: I wrote in question (mode: developer, static content and caches were cleaned) + local storage has translates in json. It was cleaned too. No affect.

Comment: > Magento is loading translation info in the following order
> > Loading the module translations. > Load theme translation file Load
> translation package info. Load db tranlation. (Inline translation) I have different translation in de_de package in module, theme and another package (vendor/{name}/language-de_de). I saw that translation got from theme always. Clear pub/static and cache (with cache in Chrome). What is the real load translation priorities?

Comment: @belfort1 deleting the `pub/static/frontend/<theme>/<theme>/js-translation.json` actually worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

[UPDATE]
Since Magento 2.2 translation load order is the following:

1. Loading the module translations.
2. Load translation package info.
3. Load theme translation file.
4. Load database translation. (Inline translation)

That basically means that translation package will overrule theme translation.
So quick and easy solution would be overcome it using Inline translation, which was also possible in M1.
But we have M2 now which has even more flexibility on board and there is a way to extend existing translation packages with custom ones. All you need to do is create another translation package.
So, create a module

> Project\Locale

create a *registration.php* for it with the following content:

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
'project_nl_nl',
__DIR__
);
```

That's how we define that module is a translation package.
Last step, create a meta-file *language.xml* with the following content:

```
<language ...>
  <code>nl_NL</code>
  <vendor>project</vendor>
  <package>nl_nl</package>
  <sort_order>10</sort_order>
  <use vendor="language" package="nl_nl" />
</language>
```

This way you specify the parent translation package you want to extend. And also specify the order, in case you already have translation package inheritance in the project.
Here is a link on example from magento [itself](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#m2devgde-xlate-inheritancework).

One more thing. Make sure that your `<vendor> . '_' . <code>` (from *language.xml*) will match module name from `registration.php`. `project_nl_nl` in my example.

Comment: Sounds great - but where exactly do I then override the translation? Yet another `nl_NL.csv` within that module?

Comment: @fritzmg yes, tranlsation file format / name is exactly the same

Comment: thx, thought so. However I still cannot get it to work, though I have opened a separate question for that: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238459/custom-language-package-not-working

Comment: Just for further readers, this answer is no longer valid. Since a long time ago, Magento changed this behavior: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Translate.php#L218

The current order is:

1) Module translation (app/code/[Vendor_Name]/i18n)
2) Language pack translation (app/i18n)
3) Theme translation (app/design/[theme]/i18n)
4) Database translation (inline)

Comment: @ManuelGarcíaSolipa yes, you are right, they changed it in 2.2. Updated the post

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found the solution. \Magento\Framework\Translate will first load theme translations and then load pack translations. You should create a plugin for this class on the method loadData, and fix the loading order.

Comment: Nice idea. How did you create a plugin? I only managed to create a preference because all other methods I needed were protected. I would be interested in a plugin-like solution.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's because now is 2019 or if [Sergey's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160688/52739) has had an error from the beginning, but the actual loading order in file *vendor/magento/framework/Translate.php* is this:

```
$this->_loadModuleTranslation();
$this->_loadPackTranslation();
$this->_loadThemeTranslation();
$this->_loadDbTranslation();
```

What gets loaded later, gets to override the previous translations.

So, even though [Daniel Sloof's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/152386/52739) works, you can just add your translation to the **theme** and it will have higher priority than a language pack.

Answer (score 1):

If clean static content, caches and translates in local storage theme CSV works, but not for some words. So, lang pack overrided by custom theme translates, but not for all phrases.