# Magento2: override vendor language package

Tags: magento2, localisation, language, vendor

I've installed the Magento2 language pack (nl_NL) from Crowdin via composer. The package is located in the vendor/magento2translations folder. I want to add some custom translations which will override the translations from the package.

Is there a possibility to add translations which will override the language pack translations? I already created a custom language pack in the app/i18n folder, added translations to my theme, added a module with translations, but none of these will override the translations from the language pack.

If I remove the translation from the language pack, it will get the right translation from my theme folder. But that isn't a solution, because our deployment automatically gets the last version of the language pack so it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem. 
There is way to define your own translation package and define dependencies and sort_order between them.
More details in this answer in [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131911/magento2-how-override-translates-in-language-pack/160688#160688)