# Override language package

Tags: magento-2.1, language

I am trying to override an installed language package ([magenerds/de_de](http://doc.magenerds.com/german-language-pack/)) with a custom package as described in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160688/52239). My problem is that my custom package is ignored, and I have no idea why.

The `magenerds/de_de` package is installed in `app/i18n/magenerds/de_de`, my custom package is in `app/i18n/projectxyz/de_de`.

`composer.json`

```
{
  "name": "projectxyz/language-de_de",
  "description": "German (Germany) language",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "require": {
    "magento/framework": "100.1.*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-language",
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

`de_DE.csv`

```
My billing and shipping address are the same,Lieferadresse als Rechnungsadresse verwenden
```

`language.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>de_DE</code>
    <vendor>projectxyz</vendor>
    <package>de_de</package>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <use vendor="magenerds" package="de_de"/>
</language>
```

`registration.php`

```
<?php

/**
 * @category   projectxyz
 * @package    projectxyz_de_de
 * @subpackage Module
 * @version    1.0.0
 * @license    OSL 3.0
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'projectxyz_de_de',
    __DIR__
);
```

Any hint what I could be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you get it to work in the mean time? I seem to have exactly the same problem.

Comment: No, sorry. I am basically maintaining a fork of that language file..