# custom language package not working

Tags: magento2, localisation, translate, language-package

Since the German translation of "Grid" within the german language pack is currently wrong (see [here](https://crowdin.com/translate/magento-2/1190/enus-de#60871)), I wanted to override it using a custom language pack (since you cannot override translations of translation packages within a module or a theme). I used the instructions provided [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160688/37461) and also looked at the [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-pack).

This is what I have so far:

`app/code/InspiredMinds/language-de_de/registration.php`:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'InspiredMinds_de_de',
    __DIR__
);
```

`app/code/InspiredMinds/language-de_de/language.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>de_DE</code>
    <vendor>InspiredMinds</vendor>
    <package>de_de</package>
    <use vendor="mageplaza" package="de_de" />
</language>
```

`app/code/InspiredMinds/language-de_de/de_DE.csv`:

```
"Grid","Raster",module,Magento_Catalog
```

Instead of

```
app/code/InspiredMinds/language-de_de
```

I also tried

```
app/i18n/InspiredMinds/de_de
```

I cleaned all caches and also ran a `setup:di:compile` (in case that is necessary for language packs). It still does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: did u try to flush 'static file cache' in cache management in admin? for my case when translation is not working correctly flushing that helps. It is available only on developer mode.
You also have the option to use the inline translation in admin panel.

Comment: Clearing the static file cache did not help unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned/suspected by @steros, there seems to be a bug with language packs regarding upper case letters within the component name. As far as I tested, the `$componentName` within `registration.php` *must not* contain uppercase letters (to fit the actual vendor and package name for example).

My above code works within

```
app/i18n/InspiredMinds/de_de
```

when I use all lower case letters as the component name in the `registration.php`:

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'inspiredminds_de_de',
    __DIR__
);
```

Everything else can stay in camel cases.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in:

`app/i18n/inspiredminds/de_de`

registration:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'inspiredminds_de_de',
    __DIR__
);
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
    <code>de_DE</code>
    <vendor>Inspiredminds</vendor>
    <package>de_DE</package>
    <use vendor="magento" package="en_us" />
</language>
```

name your csv file `de_DE.csv`.

You need to run `magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE` too depending on your setup.

Comment: That's what I already did, see my post. Whether I use `InspiredMinds` or `inspiredminds` should not matter, as long as I use the correct case in the `registration.php` and `language.xml`.

Comment: That's what I use and it works. There are some differences from your code. As far as I remember there is a bug where uppercase doesn't work. I never tried after upgrading if it still is the case though.

Comment: Apart from the case I do not see many differences. Theme and module vendor names with camel case definitely work, so I don't think that's the problem. However, you used `<use vendor="magento" package="en_us" />`, but that's wrong, since I want to override `<use vendor="mageplaza" package="de_de" />`, isn't it?

Comment: Interestingly enough, it turns out there still is a case sensitivity issue - _but only in the registration.php_. While any other reference can be left in the camel case for example, the name of the language pack in the `registration.php` needs to be all lower case.

Comment: See, I said there's a difference and a case issue  ;)

Comment: Yes :). I posted a separate answer to, to be more specific.

Comment: You could have just edited my answer...

Comment: I was thinking about that too, but since it would have been completely different I thought it makes more sense to create a separate answer.