# Magento 2: de_DE language pack not applying to de_AT

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.2.6, language-package

I am new to the Magento world and certain things are a little bit complicated for me. For example I have language pack for german language (code de_DE) purchased and installed. However my shops primary country is set to austria (de_AT).

Now all the language parts appear in english, instead of falling back to the german language. I can however create my own translation (or copy the one I have) for de_AT and then it works, but this is not desired as it creates duplicates and makes the language strings not undateable via the web setup wizard.

How can I achieve my language pack to be used? Shouldn't the fallback be on the main language part and thus fallback to de_DE anyway?

Hope anybody can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servus :)

Have you installad a `de_AT` language pack? If not, magento does not know to fall back to `de_DE`, so just set this as you default locale.

If there is an austrian language pack, it shoul inherit from `de_DE` ... example here: [Magento2: how override translates in language pack?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131911/magento2-how-override-translates-in-language-pack/160688#160688)

Comment: Servus, thank you. As i wrote, i do not have an austrian but rather a german language pack. I know i could duplicate it. But inheriting it as you pointed out in the link provided should do the trick :)

Comment: Just a follow up question here: have you ever done it and might provide an example? It just does not work for me. I have created a language module with `de_AT` code, which works when i manually include a translation file `de_AT.csv`. However i want inheritance, and once i remove my `csv` i have no translations, although i have the`<use ..>` Tag in my `language.xml`. I have https://marketplace.magento.com/dreadyhead-language-de-de.html and tried `<use vendor="dreadyhead" package="language-de_de" />` but also other combinations.