# Magento 2: Overwrite extension's i18n

Tags: magento2

I have an extension on which I would like to change a few sentences and I do not want to do that in core files, since those will be overwritten on next update.

I already tried to put files into: `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/<extension_vendor>_<extension_name>/i18n/en_US.csv` and it's not working, but if I change the original .csv file, it does work.

Is it possible to only change the specific extension's i18n file (and where to put it) or must I follow this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160688/52640 ?

Magento CE v2.2.3
Extension: Amasty Out of Stock Notification v1.9.2 CE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to put your translations into

`app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/i18n/en_US.csv`